# How to stop quests from auto failing in Fallout4 due to time restriction?

Tags: fallout-4

There are some time-limited quests in Fallout 4, that aren't communicated to the player all that well.

After quick traveling I was hit by a failed quest, and my last recent save game is too far away from the quest's location (believe me, I tried, multiple times), and the save game before that recent save game is a few game-hours in the past. So currently, I have stopped playing at all and am reconsidering an entirely new play through.

Before doing such a drastic thing: Is there a way to disable the quest time limit? Or to stop the passing of time in-game?

Comment: On consoles - I doubt it.

Comment: @DangerZone I'm on PC. So I'm hoping there is something to a console command that achieves what I am looking for.

Comment: I figured. But in case anyone on consoles has a similar need for this feature, they should also have an "answer" to this.

Comment: Are you talking about the settlement defense missions? Those things are obnoxious; I'd just ignore them. You'll lose some settlers, but that's that.

Comment: The only time-sensitive quests I'm aware of are the settlement defense missions, which are random and largely unimportant. Definitely no reason to start over.

Comment: @Nolonar I think there might be some other non-settlement related time-sensitive quests. If [this post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72869994) is to be believed, there is a part of the Silver Shroud quest that makes an optional objective fail. I actually JUST received this quest, so I can't attest to the validity... If that is the case, though, I'd better get it done pronto.

Comment: @king14nyr I'm pretty sure I've let that quest sit for quite a while. If there's a time limit, it's long. They may be referring to the very end, where you have to save the guy before the enemy kills him, but that's once you're in the same room with them.

Comment: @king14nyr I don't think that quest is time sensitive, there is a possibility of a protectron aggroing a mini-boss type character who kills an optional objective hostage though.

Comment: AFAIK the timed quests are all related to settlements (Kidnappings, Defense, 'Clearing the way') and have a pretty low impact. They're all radiant quests, so failing one won't mess up anything. Worst case scenario it was a camp defense and all the settlers are all dead, meh. Things can go wrong in the Commonwealth. If I were you I'd just roll with it, no need to start over for that.

Answer (score 4):

You could try `sgtm` to stop the passage of time but I don't recommend it. Instead use `coc` (**center on cell**) to instantly fast travel to your detestation.

E.g., `coc RedRocketExt`

To find the name that you need to enter for your intended detestation type `help {insert keyword of location here} 4`.

E.g., `help sunshine 4` yields two entries for **exterior cells**: SunshineTidingsExt and SunshineTidingsExt2.

You'd then type `coc SunshineTidingsExt`

For interior cells you may need to use the 'name' or ID that comes after the LCTN (location) headers in the help list.

---

Not recommended:

> `SetGlobalTimeMultiplier`  or `sgtm`  – Sets multiplier on in-game time.
>
> Warning: Can break quite a few things. Safe values are 0 to 25. Above 50 drops framerate and higher crashes the game. –[fallout.wikia.com](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands)

Comment: Can't you just change your system clock?

Comment: Changing the clock speed on your computer is even more highly *not* recommended. If you mean the date/time, I don't see how that would affect anything, except possibly lock you out of your copy of Windows. So, don't do that either.